# Using Java, how would I find a time behind using modulo?

Tags: java, time, modulo

I'm building a table of runners and their times.  I need to find the time behind the previous runner in minutes and seconds using modulo.  the first 2 records are

```
Runner: 198
Minutes: 29
Seconds: 05

Runner: 419
Minutes: 30
Seconds: 01
```

Time behind runner #1?

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
public class read3
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
    DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("c:\\java\\chapter13\\sheet2\\program2.jdat2"));
    int id;
    int mins;
    int secs;//,num3;
    double calc=0,calc2=0;
    char chr;
    double tcalc=0;
    double t1=0,t2=0,t3=0;
    NumberFormat money=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    System.out.println("Runner\tTotal  \tTotal  \tTime");
    System.out.println("Number\tMinutes\tSeconds\tBehind\n");
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            id=in.readInt();
            in.readChar();
            mins=in.readInt();
            in.readChar();
            secs=in.readInt();
            in.readChar();

            System.out.println(id+"\t      "+mins+"\t    "+secs+"\t"+calc);
        }
    }
    catch(EOFException e)
    {
        //Hi
    }
    in.close();
}
}
```

I just need to know the equation for finding minutes/seconds (in separate variables) using modulo.  Can anybody help?

Comment: Use `minutes*60*1000+seconds*1000+millis` to get the time in millis and then convert it back by dividing by `60*1000` for minutes and `1000` for seconds !!!!

Comment: Do you at least know how many seconds there are in a whole minute?

Comment: I 'have' to use modulus.  It's an assignment in a class and I don't recall how to use modulus, and my teacher doesn't mind asking questions on stack overflow, i tried googling it but pretty much everything is blocked

Comment: You've been given the equations, let's see you at least try applying them to your code for heaven's sake. Please prove that you're not lazy and show the fruits of your efforts.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know that modulus gets the remainder of division when dividing integers

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not trying to be lazy, I just don't know how to implement the given equations into my loop, I'm still working on it, although  haven't figured it out yet

Comment: Again, you've got the equations. Don't throw up your hands and give up -- try to apply them. You won't blow up your computer with the effort. You've nothing to lose and will gain our respect.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am trying, right now im seeing if i can use a 'hold' variable to store the previous runners time and use that as the second set of varialbes in the equations given

Answer (score 3):

```
int time1=nbMinutes1*60+nbSeconds1;
int time2=nbMinutes2*60+nbSeconds2;

int differenceInMinutes = (time2-time1)/60;
int differenceinSeconds = (time2-time1)%60;
```

EDIT:
To apply it to your code, I would do the following :

```
    Integer duration=null;

    while(true)
    {
        id=in.readInt();
        in.readChar();
        mins=in.readInt();
        in.readChar();
        secs=in.readInt();
        in.readChar();

        Integer newDuration=60*mins+secs;

        //duration is null for the first one.
        if(duration!=null){
          System.out.println(id+"\t      "+(newDuration-duration)/60+"\t    "+secs+"\t"+(newDuration-duration)%60);
        }

        duration = newDuration;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure quite how to do that inside my loop with the code-template i was given.  I'll update the question to include my code

Comment: @BrandonDurst: why don't you first try to use the modulus as shown here inside of a loop before dumping your homework code on us.

Comment: The assignment is only for creating/reading data, the modulus part is trivial, it's just the specific program I'm stuck on.  I already created the data file and I'm reading it in just fine, which is what the chapter is on

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is only tangentially associated with knowing how to use modulus. You have one master function doing a mess of things: initializing variables, opening files, iterating through rows, and figuring out display parameters. This is known as procedural programming, and bad procedural programming at that: you want to leverage object oriented programming here.

```
//note the standards regarding class names: Capitalize Class Names!
//also, pick names that make it clear what you're doing.
public class DisplayTimes 
{
  DataInputStream in;

  //This is not actually the correct way to do this, but it's lightweight enough for this example
  List<Integer> runnerIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  List<Integer> runnerMinutes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  List<Integer> runnerSeconds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  //note that your main method should not throw an exception. Nothing can catch it!!
  //also note that this is just an entry point; it probably shouldn't do any work
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    DisplayTimes display = new DisplayTimes("c:\\java\\chapter13\\sheet2\\program2.jdat2");
    display.readAndDisplay();
  }

  //constructors are the proper way to initialize object variables
  public DisplayTimes(String inputFile) { 
    //see how much easier this next line is to read?
    this.in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
  }

  public void readAndDisplay() {
    processData(); //offload processing somewhere else
    System.out.println("Runner\tTotal  \tTotal  \tTime");
    System.out.println("Number\tMinutes\tSeconds\tBehind\n");

    for (int idx = 0; idx++; idx<runnerIds.size()) {
      String output = runnerIds.get(idx)+"\t";
      output = output + runnerMinutes.get(idx)+"\t";
      output = output + runnerSeconds.get(idx)+"\t";
      output = output + calculateDifference(idx)+"\t";

      System.out.println(output);
    }
  }

  private void processData() {
    boolean moreData = true;
    while (moreData) { //offload the work of the loop to another method
      moreData = processRunner();
    }
  }

  private boolean processRunner() {
    try {
      int id=in.readInt();
      in.readChar();//how is this file formatted that you need to skip a char?
      int mins=in.readInt();
      in.readChar();
      int secs=in.readInt();

      //Here you should really sanity-check your values
      //Instead we'll just store them
      this.runnerIds.add(id);
      this.runnerMinutes(mins);
      this.runnerSeconds(secs);

      return isFinished();
    } catch (EOFException e) {
      //Exceptions should NOT be used for program control. 
      //They should be used when there is bad data.
      System.out.println("There was an unexpected termination of the datafile.");
    }

  }

  private boolean isFinished() {
    in.mark(1);
    if (in.read == -1) {//checks cleanly if we're at the end of the file.
      return false;
    } else {
      in.reset();//moves you back to mark
      return true;
    }
  }

  private String calculateDifference(int idx) {
    if (idx == 0) { return "\t"; } //First runner is first!
    int previousTimeInSeconds = (runnerMinutes.get(idx-1) * 60) + runnerSeconds.get(idx-1);
    int nextTimeInSeconds = (runnerMinutes.get(idx) * 60) + runnerSeconds.get(idx);

    int delta = (nextTimeInSeconds - previousTimeInSeconds);
    return (delta / 60) + "min " + (delta % 60) + "sec \t";
  }
}
```

The main thing you should take away here is that the problem you came here with - calculating the difference between runner a and b - is only a small part of the code you presented. You couldn't present a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) because your code was improperly tangled with other code. By writing clean code you can focus on the one function (`calculateDifference()`) that you actually needed help with. While I understand you may be beginning and working out of a book (based on what was presented), the most fundamental thing you can learn is how to break down a problem into the smallest pieces possible. Utilize the language to help you with this; don't fight it.